# Insert image into specific CLASS of a DIV

Tags: jquery, tampermonkey

with the below tampermonkey code I am able to create a new div and append it to a specific class.
I am also able to show some text but instead of this I would like to implement an image and maybe in the future a script.

Can you maybe please give me some guidance?

```
$( "<div><h1>JQuery Core</h1></div>" ).appendTo( ".vhb-c-header__content" );
```

Thanks,
Sebastian

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply append the image. You can use jQuery .append() method.

```
  $(".myclass").append("<img src='yourimage.jpg'>");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script> 
<div class="myclass"></div>



<script>

//$( "<div><h1>JQuery Core</h1></div>" ).appendTo( ".myclass" );
// to append an image:

$(".myclass").append("<img src='https://wallup.net/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/22/310241-night-blue-mountain-748x529.jpg'>");

</script>
```